# I2C master not sending ack after receiving a byte from a slave

Tags: microcontroller, i2c, lpc

I am using an NXP uC of the LPC8xx family. I have the I2C0 in master mode to receive two bytes consecutively from a slave.

It all works correctly at the beginning since the LPC send slave address and the slave acknowledges, the LPC send the register address to be read and the slave ack and then the slave sends the first byte. Then if the master had sent an ACK the slave would have sent the next byte (the one at the address next to the previous sent) but the LPC is not sending the ACK but a stop.

What should I do to make the master (i.e. the LPC8xx microcontroller) to send an ACK after receiving the first byte?

thanks in advance

Green: end of slave register address sent by the master and slave ACK

gray: first byte sent by the slave (with the missing ack from the master). Here the master only produces 8 clock pulses so it is also missing the clock pulse

yellow: master sends NACK and a stop after a while

[image]

Comment: Regardless of the number of bytes transmitted/received, each byte must be followed by an ACK. Did you check with a logic analyser or at least with a scope if SDA and SCL signals are correct? Also, please paste your code here along with hardware schematic (if possible) or a photo of the setup.

Comment: It's impossible to answer as there is no code shown. Have you written the code yourself or are you using some sort of I2C driver from manufacturer? Also based on your description, the protocol might be wrong - Writing the register address and reading the register data are two separate I2C transactions that are prefixed by a start, but the register address write does not usually need to have a stop condition so new start will suffice.

Comment: @RohatKılıç _"Regardless [..], each byte must be followed by an ACK."_ That's only true for the I2C slave when the master is transmitting. If the slave is transmitting and the master wants the transfer to stop, it sends a NACK followed by a STOP.

Comment: Hi, I am using code written by myself. I tested the I2C lines with an oscilloscope and it works as stated above. What is working not correctly is that the LPC does not acknowledge the first received byte. I attach a screenshot

Comment: Based on description and scope capture, you are either describing it wrong, or then it is wrong. If green part is the ACK of sending register address, and gray is already data sent by slave chip, that is impossible as it would be against the I2C protocol. Changing the data direction would need start and I2C address sending with the data direction bit. Please make sure you know what you are doing.

Comment: The green part is the slave addres+read sent by the master. Then the slave ACK and immediately sends the data byte. What I see from the scope is basically the last part of what shown here in section 3.2https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva704/slva704.pdf?ts=1685426949228&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F

Comment: Without code (written by yourself, which is probably the problem), we cannot help.

Comment: Most IIC controllers need to be told whether to send an ACK or a NAK in response to a byte received by a slave.  That is certainly the case with the LPX18xx series IIC controller which I have used on a number of products.

Comment: Hi steve, do you remember how to say to the I2C of the LPC18xx series to send the ACK after receiving the byte from the slave?

Comment: @tommino Yes, and the trick is, you set it up BEFORE receiving data from the slave.  Once the IIC controller has sent the slave address + R and receives an ACK from the slave, an interrupt is generated.  At that time, the I2C_I2CONCLR_AAC bit should be cleared using the CONCLR register if only one byte is to be received (i.e. the master will NAK the receeived data indicating to the slave to not send more data), conversely the I2C_I2CONSET_AA should be set using the CONSET register if more than one byte is left to be received (i.e. the master should ACK the received data).

Comment: @tommino After each received byte from the slave, you then again decide if the master should ACK or NAK the next byte using the same process as described above.